# Cant display images in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

In my code I store image names in the database and I try to retrieve images from a folder on my localhost. The folder is inside the htdocs. I tried banner(foldername)/    and http://localhost/banner/ nothing helped. Below is my code-

```
$output .= '
   <img src="http://localhost/banner/'.$row["banner_image"].'" alt="'.$row["banner_title"].'" />
```

the screenshot of db
[image]

screenshot of filestructure
[filestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4icG.png)

banner folder screenshot
[banner folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU9Kj.png)
screenshot of the code u asked to run
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev03t.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171391/discussion-on-question-by-noob-cant-display-images-in-xampp).

Answer (score 0):

maybe problem is in your path image in phpmyadmin

try update using sql

```
UPDATE `banner` SET `banner_image` = 'http://localhost/banner/banner1.jpg' WHERE `banner`.`banner_id` = 1;
```